# should schema rich snippet use for product listing too?

Tags: magento, seo, schema.org, rich-snippets

I'm implementing schema rich snippet to a Magento store for Product page, and would like to know if it's a good idea to also do it for Product listing page.

Did a search and most questions/articles are focus on Product page only, so I am wondering if it maybe counter productive for SEO purpose.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as Google is concerned, product rich snippets aren't supported in product listings:

> Use markup for a specific product, not a category or list of products.

See [Google Rich snippets - Products](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146750#usage)

Search Engine Journal offers some good advice that more specifically answers your question though:

> Depending on how the website is set up, you may choose to mark up
>   category pages. If you list product information on the category pages,
>   you will want to omit any microdata markup as it may cause a
>   confliction with the product pages. After all, the goal for
>   conversions usually starts with the product pages, so you will want
>   the product page to be the landing page rather than a category page.
>   For a simple category page that lists category names, place each
>   category name in an h1 tag and add the following microdata markup.

See [E-Commerce Microdata Best Practices](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/e-commerce-microdata-best-practices/35228/) under the Category Page Markup heading.

Their reccomendation, and it seems a good one, is to add markup to your product list template somewhat like this:

```
<ul id="category_list">
    <li itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Enumeration">
        <img src="http://url.to.image" itemprop="image" />
        <h1 itemprop="name">Category Name</h1>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. Does the code above for product listing or the category name & image? It looks to me the latter.

Also, if you know in this page, the "Warning: Page contains property "price" which is not part of the schema." provided by Google Structure Data Testing Tool is something I should worry about? http://bit.ly/RWq3Vc  My thought is that it's caused by the clone_price when a product is with Custom Options or Configurable.

Comment: Yes, the latter. @user1258365 The schema URL seems to be case sensitive so you need to use `http://schema.org/Product` rather than `http://schema.org/product`. Also `http://schema.org/Offer` and `http://schema.org/AggregateRating`

Comment: Thanks again! In the template files the schema URLs are correct per the spec. y Google Structure Data Testing Tool however is showing lowercase for the test result though.

Comment: Does anyone know the advantage of using the category list markup? According to this Google tool (http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets), it doesn't seem to change the appearance of the search result.